# Mac Safari Will Not Run Applet of Size Zero

Tags: java, css, macos, safari, applet

In an `<applet>` tag with `width=0` and `height=0` the applet code fails to load. I tried to put the applet in a hidden div, but again it wouldn't load the applet. For now I have a work around in for it to work by setting `width=1` and `height=1`.

Is there any way to hide the applet and still get it to work?

Comment: *"In an <applet> tag with width=0 and height=0 the applet code fails to load."*  I have been saying for years that a 0x0 element in HTML is suspicious, and should be removed or ignored.  It is gratifying to know that at least one browser manufacturer agrees with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to hide the applet and still get it to work?

Yes, and it is typically found in the styles.  I expect you are currently using the wrong CSS to hide it.

### Incorrect

**[display: none](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display)**

> This value causes an element to not appear in the formatting structure (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout). Descendant elements do not generate any boxes either; **the element and its content are removed from the formatting structure entirely**. ..

### Correct

**[visibility: hidden](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#visibility)**

> The generated box is **invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout.** Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.